# WKWebView Check if web view support to load a file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, wkwebview, swift5

I am create a iOS Application. I am using WKWebView at some stage to show some files of any extension types. For Audio, Video, html, text, pdf, documents files its working well. But files like .zip , .csv and many others its not showing proper data or show blank screen without any error I am getting in its navigations delegates methods.

**My Question is how can I check if my WKWebView is able to load/support that file? So that if it's not able to load or support that file, I can show another view where I will direct download that file to File manager and give user option to save or share that file.**

Like In Safari browser when I am trying to load zip file its not show any preview , its show an alert to download (in iOS 13) or show Save and share file action (in iOS 13). How Safari is detecting that its support that file or not?

> Please do not suggest to use direct String matching for mime types or extensions because there can be 1000+ files extensions in the world.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your controller as `webView.navigationDelegate` and define the navigation response delegate callback as follows:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, 
    decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

    if navigationResponse.canShowMIMEType {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        // do something else with `navigationResponse.response`
    }
}
```